# How to calculate the rolling resistance of a wheel over an obstacle?

Tags: classical-mechanics

Imagine a bicycle travelling at speed, and then rolling over a log. What are the principles behind calculating the force that is required to roll a wheel over an obstacle?

Comment: As you say in your tag, this is really a physics question, not
a mathematical one.

Comment: There's physicsoverflow.net but is has no activity

Comment: Then it's time you created some :-)

Comment: PhysicsOverflow is http://physicsoverflow.net/ .
It seems to have just launched and is awaiting its first question.
Its FAQ proclaims "No question is too trivial or too "newbie" "
(unlike MO :-) ).

Comment: I just tried to post this question for you at PhysicsOverflow. First I failed because I didn't give the question a tag; then I looked for a suitable tag, and found that there were none defined (i.e. no tags at all, suitable or unsuitable); then I tried to create a tag and it wouldn't let me because I'm a new user.
So that explains why PhysicsOverflow has no questions then.

Comment: When MathOverflow started, Anton created about 10 closed questions full of likely tags to get the ball rolling.  Maybe the PO.net people haven't realized this was necessary.  Also, the first several real questions were asked by moderators, i.e., one reason why they joined the site was because they had questions.  Incidentally, there is a physicsoverflow.com that has slightly more activity.

Comment: On the subject of your question, there seem to be many variables that need accounting.  Are you only modeling a wheel, or a bicycle?  If I were riding a bicycle over an obstacle, I'd first shift my weight back to pull the front wheel up.  Do you want to account for this in your model?  Perhaps the easiest version of your problem uses a totally inelastic collision of a wheel with a log with no slipping.  Then you only need to calculate the energy loss in the beginning and the end of the interaction.

Comment: It appears that PhysicsOverflow.net seems to have been partially set up but abandoned before being fully activated :-( 